# Not able to get facebook userdata in Smartface App Studio

Tags: smartface.io

I tried to implement facebook login for my app. 
After success login, i am trying to get userdata by following code,

```
Facebook.Social.userDetails({onSuccess : function (e) {
            alert(e.name);
        },
        onError : function () {
            alert(e.message);
        }
    });
```

But, both onSuccess and onError events is not firing.

Can any one help me pls.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Got it. :)

Should use `Social.Facebook.userDetails({})`  rather than `Facebook.Social.userDetails({});`

Thanks.